# Cochran’s Q test for binary outcome and multilevel IV

Tags: r, cochran-q

I have two variables one is the dependent variable (Blood Type)  with 2 levels and other is an independent variable with 11 levels as shown below

```
                               Blood Type
                            A              B
  -----------------------------------------------------  
  Skull                     7              26
  Back                      8               7
  But                       2               3
  Chest                    38             104
  Nose                     22              26
  Feet                      1               1
  Elbow                     6              12
  Lip                       2               8
  Thigh                     1               9
  Shoulder                  9              13
  Calf                     20              34
```

This is a repeated measure data. How do I perform **Cochran’s Q test** to detect if these two variables (DV, IV) are statistical related or not ?

I have tried the approach suggested here, `RVAideMemoire` https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_07.html and  `nonpar`  package 
https://rdrr.io/cran/nonpar/man/cochrans.q.html

However I get some error

Any suggestions and advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the data arrangement in the example you reference:  To use Cochran's Q test, you need to have a dichotomous dependent variable, a grouping variable, and then a variable indicating the subjects for which there are repeated measures....  In any case, from how you've presented your data, you don't have data in this arrangement.

From how you have presented your data and question, the best I can guess is that you want a chi-square test of independence. Or logistic regression, with a similar purpose.

```
Data = read.table(header = T, text="
  Group     Blood       Count
  Skull     A            7              
  Back      A            8               
  But       A            2              
  Chest     A           38            
  Nose      A           22             
  Feet      A            1              
  Elbow     A            6              
  Lip       A            2               
  Thigh     A            1             
  Shoulder  A            9            
  Calf      A           20              
  Skull     B           26
  Back      B            7
  But       B            3
  Chest     B          104
  Nose      B           26
  Feet      B            1
  Elbow     B           12
  Lip       B            8
  Thigh     B            9
  Shoulder  B           13
  Calf      B           34
")

Table = xtabs(Count ~ Group + Blood, data=Data)

chisq.test(Table)

   ### Pearson's Chi-squared test
   ### 
   ### X-squared = 15.597, df = 10, p-value = 0.1118
   ### 
   ### Warning message:
   ### In chisq.test(Table) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

model = glm(Blood ~ Group, weights=Count, data=Data, family=binomial())

library(car)

Anova(model, test="Wald")

   ### Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)
   ### 
   ###       Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
   ### Group 10 14.734     0.1421
```